# Android permission, как узнать где и как используется определённое разрешение?

Tags: android, java

в документации описано множество [permission](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html), там есть очень много интересных и полезных для списка программ которые я хотел бы реализовать.

часть из них помечены "Not for use by third-party applications." "не для использования сторонними приложениями" что конкретно это означает?

в общем хотелось бы увидеть где и как используется определённое разрешение.

я конечно могу погуглить "android.permission.INJECT_EVENTS How and where used" но может есть где сборник\описание всех разрешений? (особенно "Not for use by third-party applications.")

Comment: "Not for use by third-party applications." означает, что это для системных приложений, т.е. для приложений, которые встраиваются в прошивку.

Comment: @Lucky_spirit я правильно понял что если указываем данный тип разрешения то для установки нужен root-доступ? а кроме этого есть "подводные камни" ?

Comment: Нет, иногда даже ROOT не спасает. Например, для того, чтобы использовать INJECT_EVENTS нужен не root, а чтобы приложение было подписано, как системное. Если даже девайс рутован, но приложение не подписано, как системное, то приложение вылетит с ошибкой при внедрении каких-нибудь events.